# What is the best way to query data between two tables which is not directly related

Tags: mysql, sql, database-design, relational-database

What is the best way to query data between two tables which is not directly related, but through third or even fourth table, that's related using foreign keys?

Something like `1 -> 2 -> 3 -> 4`.

I saw many very different suggestions, but would like to find out what could be the best way in such situation, where I try to maintain relational database model but also avoid super complicated SQL queries.

Here is example that matches my case:

```sql
CREATE TABLE `user` (
    `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `name` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
    `city_id` int(11) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
CONSTRAINT `fk_city_id` FOREIGN KEY (`city_id`) 
    REFERENCES `city` (`id`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=3 ;
```

```sql
CREATE TABLE `city` (
    `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `name` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
    `country_id` int(11) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
CONSTRAINT `fk_country_id` FOREIGN KEY (`country_id`) 
    REFERENCES `country` (`id`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=3 ;
```

```sql
CREATE TABLE `country` (
    `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `name` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
    `continent_id` int(11) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
CONSTRAINT `fk_continent_id` FOREIGN KEY (`continent_id`) 
    REFERENCES `continent` (`id`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=3 ;
```

```sql
CREATE TABLE `continent` (
    `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `name` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=3 ;
```

Lets say I want to get all users from specific **Continent**

```sql
SELECT name FROM user WHERE city_id IN (
    SELECT id FROM city WHERE country_id IN (
        SELECT id FROM country WHERE continent_id = 1 ) ) );
```

It looks fine, I guess, but what if I want to get all users from specific **City**

```sql
SELECT name FROM user WHERE city_id IN (
  SELECT id FROM city WHERE country_id IN (
    SELECT id FROM country WHERE continent_id = (
      SELECT continent_id FROM country WHERE id = (
        SELECT country_id FROM city WHERE id = 1 ) ) ) );
```

Is this efficient?

Maybe it's possible to achieve the same with JOIN?

I tried to avoid adding all values to user table, as to maintain that relation `city->country->continent` and involve relations to do the job, but maybe in this case it's just not worth doing so? ..maybe not efficient, and it's better to redesign database?

Comment: IN statements are bad... JOIN are better when indexes are in place..

Comment: Can place your tables and example data on SQLfriddle? http://sqlfiddle.com  then i will show you some JOIN examples

Comment: Here http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1c40e/1 is working example on SQLFiddle.com, thanks for sharing link

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Should be something like this and you may want to analyse (**with explain why an JOIN is better vs subquery**) EXPLAIN manual page http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/explain.html

**Please note that you can only trust INNER JOIN with filters like below with LEFT JOIN or RIGHT JOIN you can get wrong results..**

**For all users within an continent with continent_id = 1**

```
SELECT
 user.name 

FROM
 user

INNER JOIN 
 city
ON
 user.city_id = city.id

INNER JOIN 
 country
ON
  city.country_id = country.id
 AND
  country.continent_id = 1
;
```

**For all users within an city with city_id = 1**

```
SELECT
 user.name 

FROM
 user

INNER JOIN 
 city
ON
  user.city_id = city.id
 AND
  city.id = 1
```

see http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1c40e/23

Answer (score 1):

Inner joins

```
-- get users to cities
from
 City c
 inner join Users u
  on c.Id = u.City_Id

-- users to continents
from
 Users u
 inner join City ci
  on u.City_id = ci.Id
 inner join Country co
  on ci.Country_Id = co.Id
 inner join Continent con
  on co.Continent_Id = con.Id
```